# Facebook share does not show the same data as the debugger

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to set the share data with og meta tags. In the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) it shows as expected. In particular the first image should be the default image. But when I go and try and share it, the data is different. there are different images, and the first image is not default.

this is the url: http://www.stepupforisrael.com/israel-apartheid-week/

here is the url in the debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stepupforisrael.com%2Fisrael-apartheid-week%2F

here is the url when trying to share:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stepupforisrael.com/israel-apartheid-week/

Answer (score 0):

According to the Facebook developer site, you need to add three tags for the image in order to allow Facebook to display the open graph image on the first share. The tags are:

1. og:image
2. og:image:width
3. og:image:height

See "Pre-caching images" on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Example:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://sanangeloera.com/sites/default/files/styles/opengraph/public/88113-1460754001-1.jpg?itok=z_0Jqpcu" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="675" />
```